# NHibernate sending Update queries for get-only transaction

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Sometimes I see in log (NHibernate.SQL) that this code causes `update` sql queries for entity when I commit transaction.

```
using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        entity = session.Get<E>(id);
        session.Transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Why it happens?

Stack trace:

```
 at NHibernate.AdoNet.Util.SqlStatementLogger.LogCommand(String message, IDbCommand command, FormatStyle style) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\Util\SqlStatementLogger.cs:line 56
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:line 191
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\NonBatchingBatcher.cs:line 40
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 2776
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 2702
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 2957
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute() in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Action\EntityUpdateAction.cs:line 79
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:line 136
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:line 125
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:line 171
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs:line 241
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEventListener.cs:line 20
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 1507
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit() in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Transaction\AdoTransaction.cs:line 193
```

The updated property looks like:

```
    public virtual MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
```

and is mapped to `integer not null` database column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of mapping enums is:

```
public class EnumConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomType(instance.Property.PropertyType);
    }

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property != null);
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Type.IsEnum);
    }
}
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of

1. dirty checking and
2. flush on commit

Imagine that you have column in DB

```
Age [int] NULL  -- Nullable column
```

but the mapping says not nullable:

```
<property name="Age" not-null="true" />
```

and C# property is also not nullable

```
public virtual int Age { get; set; }
```

And if such record is loaded with **`null`** value - entity's property **`Age`** is set to **0**.

In such scenario... NHiberante knows that value has changed, and tries to on FLUSH (commit) make DB and application aligned. That's why there is write operation executed... Just an example, but in a nut-shell those are the cases

Comment: I included in the question that the property is of enum type and is mapped to `not null` column. Can enum-integer conversation cause it?

Comment: check what is the db value and the C# values of that enum

Comment: The db value is 1 and the C# enum value corresponds it.